# issue adding 'access wifi information capability' to Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, entitlements

I need to add the 'Access WiFi Information'capability to an Xcode 10.2 project. When I toggle the capability on, a little red exclamation mark appears with the message "Add the Access Wifi Information to your entitlements file' and a 'fix issue' button. If I click that button, I can see the capability get added to the entitlements file, but as soon as I build it gets removed again and the red exclamation mark comes back. I've deleted Derived Data, cleaned build folder, and have regenerated and redownloaded provisioning profiles but these have not fixed the issue. Does anyone know why this is happening?
[image]

Comment: Please try following this guide: https://medium.com/better-programming/wifi-permission-changes-for-ios-12-1-iphone-x-and-other-devices-c313e24f90ae

Comment: thanks - I have been following that guide, but still having the above issue.